# How can I show a page that not exists with PHP?

Tags: php

I have a website that show information about a shop online. I need following:

When you type `example.com/shop/name-shop`, this should  show the **name-shop page.**

I'd like only have the file `example.com/shop.php` which show the information of shop based on the **URL**. I don't like  use `example.com/shop?name-shop`.

Is this possible or I need to create one file to each shop? I tried to do this with an error page and a header location and works fine but in the url show `example.com/shop` instead of `example.com/shop/name-shop`.

Thanks.

EDIT:
I'm using the .htaccess in Apache with `ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php` In the file error404.php I've a if to check if url is `http://example.com/shop/*` When the url contains /shop/ redirect with `header ("location: website")` to the correct shop and works. But in the url in browser only show `example.com/shop` instead `example.com/shop/name-shop`. Obviously because i'm redirecting to shop.php

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the web server you are using, you will need to use rewriting rules ([mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for Apache) or 404 pages to show custom content on each URL using only one PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use Symfony2. You can define routes with placeholders and you have a FrontController, which would correspond to your shop.php file.